# Self-referencing Many to Many relationship in EF Database first

Tags: entity-framework

Is there a way to map multiple foreign keys to the same navigation property of an entity? I have a table with a self-referencing many to many relationship defined by a relationship table.

For example, I have a Person table and I want to define the different related people. I created another table, PersonRelationship, that defines those relationships with 2 foreign keys to the Person table. It doesn't matter if the person is referenced in the first or the second foreign key just that the person is in one. I would like my Person entity to have a list of all the relationships but instead it has two lists of relationships: one in which the person is in the first foreign key and another where it is the second foreign key.

How can I map these two foreign keys so that they map to the same list in the Person entity? (I am using a database first approach)